# Add item to RecyclerView when Contact is clicked

Tags: android

I want to add item to RecyclerView when i choose Contact from contactbook

It's can be use in text view i can but i find how to use in recycler

i get two String like contactname and numberphne from Contact book and i need add it to view and show in recyclerview

Here is my code for RecyclerView Adapter

```
public class SettingCallAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SettingCallAdapter.ViewHolder>{


private Context context;
private List<Hospital> data;
private int lastSelectedPosition = 0;

public SettingCallAdapter( Context context , List<Hospital> data){
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;

}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_setting_message_radio , parent , false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Hospital hospital = data.get(position);

    holder.name.setText(hospital.getHos_name());
    holder.num.setText(hospital.getHos_tel());
    holder.selectionState.setChecked(lastSelectedPosition == position);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size() ;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView name , num;
    public RadioButton selectionState;



    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.set_name);
        num = itemView.findViewById(R.id.set_num);
        selectionState = itemView.findViewById(R.id.select_state);
        selectionState.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                lastSelectedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my MainActivity

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_setting);
    TextView title = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_back));
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    title.setText(toolbar.getTitle());
    title.setText("การแจ้งเหตุฉุกเฉิน");

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRef = mDatabase.getReference().child("setting").child("hospital");

    set_button = findViewById(R.id.setting_edit_button);
    set_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    save_button = findViewById(R.id.setting_save_button);
    save_button.setOnClickListener(this);

    show_num = findViewById(R.id.show_num_call);
    add_num = findViewById(R.id.add_num_call);
    add_contact_message = findViewById(R.id.add_contact_message);

    message = findViewById(R.id.set_message);
    message.setEnabled(false);

    add_num_call = findViewById(R.id.recycler_add_num_call);

    show_num_message_list = findViewById(R.id.recycler_show_num_message);
    add_num_message_list = findViewById(R.id.recycler_add_num_message);

    select_contact = findViewById(R.id.add_contact_call);
    select_contact.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Check Keyboard
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Hospital mHospital = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Hospital.class);

                list_hospital.add(mHospital);
            }

            mAdapter = new SettingCallAdapter(SettingActivity.this , list_hospital);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            add_num_call.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            add_num_call.setHasFixedSize(true);
            add_num_call.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(SettingActivity.this));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
     @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.setting_edit_button:
            set_button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            save_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            show_num.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            add_num.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            add_contact_message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            show_num_message_list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            message.setEnabled(true);

            addNumSOS();


            break;

        case R.id.setting_save_button:
            save_button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            set_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            show_num.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            add_num.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            add_contact_message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            show_num_message_list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            message.setEnabled(false);

            addMessageSOS();

            break;

        case R.id.add_contact_call:
            Intent contactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(contactIntent , RESULT_PICK_CONTACT);
    }
}

    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_PICK_CONTACT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri contactUri = data.getData();
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int phoneIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

        name_contact = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
        num_contact = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
    }
                Hospital hospital= new  Hospital();
                hospital.setHos_name(name_contact);
                hospital.setHos_tel(num_contact);
                list_hospital.add(hospital);
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(list_hospital.size()-1);
        }
```

EDIT: How i can use difference View in my code it mean like i feed form data use **view_1**  and when i add data use **view_2**

This Image show difference view when i add view_2 have a delete button it form ios phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few things wrong with your code. Since you have add a `ValueEventListener` `onDataChange` will be trigger everytime something happens to your `mRef`. That is ok. But the thing is you have set the adapter and the layout manager on that event and every time the recyclerview's adapter change when something happen to that `mRef`.

Here is how to do it properly. 
Put the following code inside the `onCreate` method below `add_num_call = findViewById(R.id.recycler_add_num_call);` line.

```
    add_num_call.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(SettingActivity.this));
    mAdapter = new SettingCallAdapter(SettingActivity.this , list_hospital);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            add_num_call.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Then inside `onDataChange` you can add the item to your adapter and notify the change like below.

```
 for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Hospital mHospital = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Hospital.class);
                list_hospital.add(mHospital);
 }
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

As for your question, you can do this on your `onActivityResult`.

```
Hospital hospital= new  Hospital();
hospital.setHos_name(name_contact);
hospital.setHos_tel(num_contact);
list_hospital.add(hospital);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// or better to use ---> mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(list_hospita.size()-1);
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank Sir That's work for me but i find out more question plz see my edit

Comment: use `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ` instead of `mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(list_hospita.size()-1);` . check whether  your `name_contact` and `num_contact` is bank or not.

And you can put the delete on the same view. you dnt need a second view to do that.

Comment: it same as notifyiteminserted

Answer (score 0):

check whether number and name is empty or not